# OpenCvSharp: CvtSeqToArray crashes

Tags: c#, opencv

I am searching a contour, and at least one is found, as I can see with the debugger.
When I try to transform the sequence into an array of points a StackOverflowException (that's why I am here :-) is thrown.

I am sure the reason is some wrong allocation of buffers, I am a bit confused with the examples I have found in C, C++, but not in C#. OpenCvSharp uses generics which I never used before.

Platform: Windows 7 on x86, Sharpdevelop 4.2.2

Here follows the code snippet:

```
OpenCvSharp.CvMemStorage    allContours = new OpenCvSharp.CvMemStorage();
OpenCvSharp.CvSeq<OpenCvSharp.CvPoint> contour = null;
OpenCvSharp.CvPoint[]   border;

  i = OpenCvSharp.Cv.FindContours (image[EDGE], allContours, out contour,
    OpenCvSharp.CvContour.SizeOf, OpenCvSharp.ContourRetrieval.List,
    OpenCvSharp.ContourChain.ApproxNone,
    OpenCvSharp.Cv.Point(0,0));
  if (i!=1)
  { Forms.MessageBox.Show( i.ToString() + " instead of 1 contours found", "Info");
    return;
  }
  border = new OpenCvSharp.CvPoint [contour.Total];
  OpenCvSharp.Cv.CvtSeqToArray<OpenCvSharp.CvPoint> (contour, out border);
```

It is the last line where the program crashes.